# Caml query returning multiple lists

Tags: 2010, list, client-object-model, caml-query, list-item

Trying to load a list from library containing two files. The following code when tested in [CamlBuilder](http://www.u2u.be/res/tools/camlquerybuilder.aspx) it is returning single row according to the filename selected. But in the program it is returning the whole library regardless of the filename queried

```
  private Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List list;
  CamlQuery q = new CamlQuery();
  q.ViewXml = @"<Query>
                            <Where> 
                                 <Eq>
                                    <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />
                                    <Value Type='File'>"+ fileName + @"</Value>
                                  </Eq>
                             </Where>
                          </Query>";
  var items = list.GetItems(q);
  cc.Load(items);
 //cc is the client context
  cc.ExecuteQuery();
  var item = items[0];
  cc.ExecuteQuery();
  var fileRef = item["FileRef"].ToString();
...
```

Please Help.. Thanks.

Comment: Where do you set the list variable? Could you include that code as well?

Comment: list is just a sharepoint list field declared global to the class.

Comment: Why the second cc.ExecuteQuery() without loading anything else in between? Perhaps that's throwing it off?

Comment: I don't know why that would affect it, but I don't see anything else odd about your query at first glance.

Comment: well thanks for the input, just now figured out wrapping the query inside <View> tag fixed the issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping the Query inside "View" tags fixed the issue. Its only returning according to the filename now.

```
q.ViewXml = @"<View>
                    <Query>
                            <Where> 
                                 <Eq>
                                    <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />
                                    <Value Type='File'>"+ fileName + @"</Value>
                                  </Eq>
                             </Where>
                          </Query>
                     </View>";
```